# How can I store unused silver conductive glue? Is it possible?

Tags: electrically-conductive, glue

I purchased some silver conductive glue.  How can I store the unused portion of glue so the needle and the metal portion won't get clogged up after its first use?  I purchased it from Amazon a while back and the product is no longer offered.

[image]

Comment: Generally, I can only reiterate: If you buy something, make sure it comes with sufficient documentation. Storage conditions definitely belong to "sufficient documentation". If the seller or manufacturer doesn't provide that essential bit, don't buy there. Anyway, depends on what hardens the glue: if it's contact with air, seal airtight. If it's exposure to UV light, store in darkness. If it's pressure, store safely away from mechanical forces. If its another chemical, contact to flat surfaces, vibration, temperature, one-time compression – avoid exactly that environment.

Comment: I purchased it from amazon awhile back and the product is no longer offered.  Next time I'll be sure to get the information.

Comment: @RickT Silver conductive glue is readily available, just maybe not from the seller you purchased it from originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as is most likely, it dries on contact with air, then one solution is to put a "rubber" block into the protective tube such that it closes the needle aperture or the needle pushes into the block. (It needs to be soft enough but tough enough. A pencil eraser may be a good start.) That way the air in the protective cap will not cause the material to dry so rapidly, however, don't expect an indefinite storage life once it is opened. If it is something you use once a day then it should be fine.